# Causes of Unable To Validate Data

Tags: .net, asp.net, viewstate

I'm getting "Unable to validate data" in a webfarm scenario but not all the time. I'm getting it about on AVERAGE 1x or 2x per hour but fairly random. All of the causes of this error that I know of are list below:

1. Machinekey in the machine.config (or web.config) not set the same in a web farm scenario. Mine are set the same in the machine.config.
2. A page is submitted after a server recycle and the machinekey is set to auto. I'm using a static key which should eliminate this source.
3. A postback is triggered before a page is loaded. I'm using 3.5 SP1 with the render viewstate at top set to true.
4. A page that post back to another page or uses server transfer. I'm not.
5. Serializing an anonymous type into the viewstate
6. Anti-virus programs or web accelerators on client machine.
7. A malicious attempt to modify viewstate

---

These are all of the sources that I know. Any other sources appreciated. Is this fairly typical to see this error 10x-20x times per day?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same errors from time to time from a bunch of our 'heavier' internal applications.  I have been at a user's desk when the error was created (logs show the time and user) and there was never actually an error presented to the users.  I think it can happen when a user switches requests quickly without the page acutally loading and only partial data is transmitted to the server.

Does the page use ViewState heavily?  Eg. controls that repeat like `GridView`, `Repeater`, `ListView`, etc...

It is very rare in the cases I have seen but you should try and verify if a user actually sees this error.

I have actually thought of putting a button on our custom error page in certain cases that says, 'click me if you see this error page' but have never actually implemented it.